# Azure Data Factory - How to create multiple datasets and apply different treatments on files in same blob container?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Starting up with Azure Data factory here.

I have a scenario where I gather csv files (different sources and formats/templates) that I store in a single Azure blob container. I would like to extract the data to an SQL DB. I need to apply different treatments to the files before pushing the data to SQL, based on the format. The format is indicated in each file name (for example: Myfile-**formatA**-20201201).

I am unclear on my pipeline / datasets setup. I assume I need to create a new (input) dataset for each CSV format, but cannot find a way to create differentiated datasets by relying on the different naming pattern. If creating a single input dataset instead, I can create a pipeline with differentiated copy activity using the same single dataset created in input and applying different filtering rules (relying based on my files naming pattern) - which seems to be working fine for files having the same encoding, column delimiters etc.. but as expected, fails for other files that do not.

I could not find any official information on how to to apply filters on creating multiple datasets from files contained in the same container. Is it possible at all? Or is a prerequisite to store files with different format in different containers or directories?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be a good idea to have a read over [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It is a good idea to include a basic working example as texts to avoid any heavy lifting. Also, you are more likely to get a positive response from the community by including some more relevant tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test to copy different format csv in one pipeline.Then select different copy activities according to the file name. I think this is the answer you want.

1. In my container, I created csv in two formats:
   [image]
2. Creat a dataset to the `input` container:
   [image]

Edit: Do not specify a file in the File Path

3. Using `Get Metadata1` activity to get the `Child items`.
   [image]
   The output is as follows:
   [image]
4. Then in `ForEach1` activity, we can traverse this array. Add dynamic content `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems` to the **Items** tab.
   [image]

5.Inside `ForEach1` activity, we can use `Switch1` activity and add dynamic content `@split(item().name,'-')[1]` to the **Expression**. It will get the format name. Such as: `Myfile-formatA-20201201` -> `formatA`.
[image]

6. Case default, we can copy csv files of fortmatA.
   [image]

Edit: in order to select only files of with "formatA" in their name, in the copy activity, use the Wildcard file path option:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmBEW.png)

7. Key in `@item().name` , so we can specify one csv file.
   [image]
8. Add `formatB` case:
   [image]
   Then use the same source dataset.
   [image]

Edit: as in previous step, use the Wildcard file path option:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3lQl.png)

That's all. We can set different `sink` at these Copy activities.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Not sure about step 7 (is this on defining the target dataset?). After researching further, I found that I could use a wildcard in the File path parameter of the copy activity in order to process only files mentioning the correct format in their filename, so have submitted an edit of your answer  accordingly.